# Symfony 6 multi auth guard

Tags: authentication, symfony, symfony6

I am working with symfony version 6 and doing a feature for client login
I have 3 auth and had problems with guard Customer

- 1 admin
- 2 merchant
- 3 customers

**admin** and **merchant** same entity **User**, customer entity **Customer**

- **merchant**  router: domain.com/merchant
- **admin** router: domain.com/admin
- and **customer**  is /* (domain.com/* all page)
  and Customer has **no role**

The problem occurs when I have successfully logged in but can't use **getUser()** on pages other than /account or /account/login for example, **home page or product page, articles...etc**

my providers

```
providers:
        sonata_user_bundle:
            id: sonata.user.security.user_provider
        customer_user_provider:
            id: customer.security.user_provider
```

my firewalls

```
firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
#        main:
#            lazy: true
#            provider: users_in_memory
        admin:
            lazy: true
            pattern: /admin(.*)
            provider: sonata_user_bundle
            context: user
            form_login:
                login_path: sonata_user_admin_security_login
                check_path: sonata_user_admin_security_check
                default_target_path: sonata_admin_dashboard
            logout:
                path: sonata_user_admin_security_logout
                target: sonata_user_admin_security_login
            remember_me:
                secret: '%env(APP_SECRET)%'
                lifetime: 2629746
                path: /admin
            # activate different ways to authenticate
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#the-firewall

            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
            # switch_user: true
        customer:
            pattern: ^/(customer/|account/*)|^/.*|^/(shopping/)
            provider: customer_provider
            form_login:
                login_path: customer_login
                check_path: customer_login
                enable_csrf: true
                username_parameter: _email
                default_target_path: customer_account
        main:
            pattern:      .*
            context:        user
            provider:       sonata_user_bundle
            user_checker: App\Security\UserChecker
            form_login:
                enable_csrf:    true
                login_path:     app_login
#                use_forward:    false
                check_path:     app_login
#                failure_path:   null
                default_target_path: app_vendor
                #success_handler: authentication.handler.login_form_success_handler
            logout:
                path: app_logout
```

controller customer

```
class CustomerController extends FrontAbstractController
{
    public function __construct(
        private RequestStack $requestStack
    )
    {
       
    }

    #[Route('account/', name: 'customer_account')]
    public function account()
    {
        return $this->render('themes/simba/customer/index.html.twig');
    }

    #[Route('account/login', name: 'customer_login',)]
    public function login(AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils, Request $request): Response
    {
        // get the login error if there is one
        $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
        // last username entered by the user
        $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();
        return $this->render('themes/simba/customer/login.html.twig', [
            'email' => $lastUsername,
            'error' => $error,
        ]);
    }

}
```

Security

```
class AppCustomerAuthenticator implements UserProviderInterface
{
    public function __construct(
        private DocumentManager       $documentManager,
        private CustomerRepository    $customerRepository
    )
    {

    }


    public function refreshUser(UserInterface $user)
    {
        $reloadedUser = $this->documentManager->find(Customer::class,$user->getId());
        if (null == $reloadedUser) {
            throw new UserNotFoundException(sprintf('User with ID "%s" could not be reloaded.', $user->getEmail() ?? ''));
        }
        $reloadedUser->setVendor($this->customerRepository->getCustomerInfo($reloadedUser));
        return $reloadedUser;
    }

    public function supportsClass($class): bool
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function loadUserByIdentifier(string $identifier): UserInterface
    {
        $customer = $this->customerRepository->getCustomer($identifier);
        if ($customer == null) {
            throw new UserNotFoundException(sprintf('Email "%s" does not exist.', $identifier));
        }
        return $customer;
    }
}
```

access_control:

```
access_control:
        # The WDT has to be allowed to anonymous users to avoid requiring the login with the AJAX request
        - { path: ^/wdt/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/profiler/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/js/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/css/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

        - { path: ^/login$, role: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
        - { path: ^/register, role: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
        - { path: ^/logout, role: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
        - { path: ^/user, role: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: ^/merchant/register, role: PUBLIC_ACCESS}
        - { path: ^/merchant/login, role: PUBLIC_ACCESS}
        - { path: ^/merchant, role: ROLE_VENDOR }
        - { path: ^/admin/login$, role: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
        - { path: ^/admin/logout$, role: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
        - { path: ^/admin/login_check$, role: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
        - { path: ^/admin/request$, role: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
        - { path: ^/admin/check-email$, role: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
        - { path: ^/admin/reset/.*$, role: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/.*, role: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
```

Thank you for reading my article, have a good evening

I have tried many ways and hope to find a solution